# Sort Table view from API

Tags: swift, api

in swift UIKit

I am trying to arrange the data in Table View according to the string variable from API

But it gives me an error

```
 var arrTable = [ModelApiData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            for i in arrTable {
             
                arrTable.sorted(by: i.url)
            }
            arrTable.sorted(by: ModelApiData)
    }
```

name (url) I want to arrange the cells on it

```
{
    "id": 130,
    "user_id": 1,
    "title": "test Sort 2",
    "details": "ESFFESFSD",
    "image_path": null,
    "youtube_link": null,
    "font_size": 19,
    "algiment": "right",
    "color": "0 0 0 1",
    "url": "2",
    "category_id": 2
},
```

error is

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '(ModelApiData, ModelApiData) throws -> Bool'
```

Also, if I use this method, I cannot determine from API

```
arrTable.sorted(by: ModelApiData)
```

Comment: You cannot use `arrTable.sorted(by: ModelApiData)`. You can use like `arrTable.sorted(by: >)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 arrTable.sorted(by: {$0.url > $1.url})
```

chose your own ascending or descending sorting way

```
arrTable.sorted(by: {$0.url > $1.url})
```

i ll suggest u to make func of sorting

```
func sortingData(array:[ModelApiData]) -> [ModelApiData] {
   return array.sorted(by: {$0.url > $1.url})
}
```

then use it to number of item in section and

```
sortingData(array:arrTable).count
```

and in cell for row at

```
let data = sortingData(array:arrTable)[indexPath].row
cell.textLabel.text = data.title
```

Comment: Beautiful, he succeeded with me through the method that I sent
But make a modification in the trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt method

The order is in reverse of the order of the cells
I mean when you open the modification, you see that it is a different cell than the one you opened

Comment: thats bcuz you are not getting the object with func sortingData you get it with arrTable[indexPath.row]  so change it to sortingData(array:arrTable)[indexPath.row] 
everywhere in all TableView functions like didSelectRowAt cell for row at ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes not sense for several reasons:

- The error tells you that you cannot sort just by passing the type. You have to specify one or multiple properties and apply the `<` operator.
- `sorted` returns the sorted array, it does not sort in place.
- Sorting in a loop is pointless.

To sort the array by the `url` property you have to write

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrTable.sort(by: {$0.url < $1.url})
}
```

Side note: Avoid optionals as much as possible.